# Resolve getting a sorted list when using 'getFeatures()' method

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, list

[image]

I have this code which allows to insert features in a list:

```
liste = []
for b in layer2.getFeatures():
    for a in layer1.getFeatures():        
        if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
            liste.append(a[12])

print liste
```

Normaly I expect this result `[67,34,35,68]`,
but the output of my code give me a sorted list `[34,35,67,68]`.
How can I resolve this problem?

---

THE COMPLETE CODE:

```
sel=[] 

for a in layer1.getFeatures():
    for b in layer2.getFeatures():   
        if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
            sel.append(a)
            print a['CODE_CH1']

b = len(sel)
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
d.setEllipsoidalMode(True)

for i in range(b-1):
    j=i+1
    if i<j:
        a = d.measureLine(sel[i].geometry().asPoint(),sel[j].geometry().asPoint())       
        print sel[i][12],sel[j][12],a
```

Comment: no they are not sorted. i just need the good order of in my list. i mean [67,34,35,68] instead of [34,35,67,68]

Comment: how can i check that my attributes are sorted? thks

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect that result please? The list will not be sorted unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: i have a layer of line and a layer of points. My goal is to caculate the length of each segments of my line.. i can edit my question and add a picture so you will see better

Comment: as you can see in the picture i want the distance between each segment. that is why i want the correct order of attributes in my lis